# Using react router v4 correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

my first time posting so please bear with me.
Recently i've decided to start learning react and i've been working on a small library application for that reason.

The part that's currently troubling me is the routing, i want to do it with react-router v4 but i can't wrap my head around it. I've gone through the official documentation and a lot of youtube guides/stack overflow questions these past few days but i couldn't find the answer i was looking for. The application is written in MERN stack(mongodb, express, react, node). Since the code from the application is quite large, i'll provide a [gist link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f63476535216edfca981c9f0968e4437) so please check it out.

What i'm trying to achieve is to change the url routes when the user clicks on any of the buttons in the admin panel(to '/books', '/members', '/checkouts' etc...), and also keep/update the history object so the browser back and forward buttons work as expected.

What would be the best way to do that with react router?
Thanks

Comment: The basic example should work : https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: i have struggled like you. watched alot of videos , read blogs and what not. but sometimes it dosent make sense.  after all the research i have done i was able to do it and understand it well. i have created a started pack for react-redux and router v4. you can have a look there its well designed structure you can learn from 
https://github.com/hannadrehman/react-redux-starter

Comment: @hannadrehman Thanks for the link it didn't solve my problem but it will help me a lot when i move on to redux and testing!

Comment: @Axnyff I've tried the basic example otherwise i wouldn't be posting a question here, but nevertheless this does work as expected after i figured out what was really causing the issue in my case.

Comment: @BorivojZaric routing is implemented in ```src/App/index.jsx``` and ```src/App/Routes/index.jsx``` that according to me is a good way to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out that my main App component that was being wrapped in the routers BrowserRouter component and had Link/Route components in it's child components was also being server rendered on load without the routers support for server side rendering and that was the real issue. Works as expected with react routers server side routing support.